# How do I find a value in a sheet connected to a google form?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to find a value in a sheet that is connected to a google form. But I dont know how. Here's what I want to do:

People are signing up to a meeting in a Google Form. The Form creates a Spreadsheet with peoples names, adresses, emailadresses etc. I want to send a confirmation mail with the information from the signup. People are asked to pay for the signup on a mobile app used in my country: mobilePay. If the user wants to pay via "mobilePay" i want to give them a sort of "booking number" in the confirmation mail.

So, I want to send a mail. I create a Google Script that - when triggered onSubmission - send that mail. That piece of code is pretty simple to make. But I want to create a function that either creates that booking number, or find that number in the spreadsheet. If I could create that booking number on the first sheet things would be a lot more easy, cause I could just link to it in the mail. But my spreadsheet will not let me create that column. Its removed whenever someone submits a new name. So I have to create that number on Sheet2 or in the script.

Are anyone able to help me out?

Comment: What is the logic behind the booking number? Is it random? If you could give some example data as well as your current code we can help you. Otherwise this question is too incomplete.

Comment: It's not random, just yyyymm-x, x is a number that counts one up for every new submission. There's not so much code yet, just some vars defining persons names, adresses, mails and so on. Then there's a mail function where I assemble the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your form responses are in columns **A:F**.

In column G you can put your formula for making the booking number. Type this in Cell **G1**

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="Timestamp",,IF(A1:A="",,YEAR(A1:A)&IF(LEN(MONTH(A1:A))=2,MONTH(A1:A),"0"&MONTH(A1:A))&"-"&Row(A1:A)-1)))
```

As the first row will be untouched by new submissions, it will populate every row even when a new one is added by a form.

Comment: This formula creates for the first submission this value: 201507-1 ?

Comment: How can you get 07 if it's still June? It gets the year and the month of the form submission and add's x

Comment: Oh, I have updated my formula. Put it in the first row instead, and yes assuming the first submission will be in July, the value in **G2** will be 201507-1

Comment: Okay, I'll try that when I get home from work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, the formula works. I pasted it in **G1**. I get an error in **G1** but the bookingnumbers are coming fine in **G2** +

Comment: Okay, the formula works. I pasted it in **G1**. I get an error in **G1** but the bookingnumbers are coming fine in **G2** and so on. I wondered if I could use another formula in **H1** that sums the last to integers in two colums, but I can't find a way to do that. If I do what brady says right under this, the Google Form erases the formula, even though it is placed after the Forms colums. Could you please help me?

Comment: Use an ArrayFormula() like I did. Then, if you put it in **H1**, it will go all teh way down and not get erased by form submission

Comment: Okay, I solved it! ;) I should just do what you told me!

Comment: Thanks Akshin for helping me!

Comment: Well it's sort of answered. The value I get from that arrayformula, how do I find it in my Google script? If I write " var bookingNumber = e.values[ a number to the corresponding column ]" it returns undefined. Yes I know about zero indexing.

Comment: That is because e has form responses, and booking number is not one of them. Instead get the data range from last row of the responses sheet and use them

Comment: Do I have to define the sheet? Like in getActiveSheet? Or can I just call it with getRange?

Comment: Better use getSheetByName("form responses 1") substitute the sheet name

Comment: I just went on a vacation with my family. I'll get back to it when I get home. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different asks here. Let me solve your simplest one first: **a column for booking number**.

If you're using the form/spreadsheet integration provided by google, you have to leave the form fields where they are. They will be organized in the order of the questions on your form. You can however add additional columns after the form data. So if you have columns A-K, you can add column L and it will not be affected by a new form submission.

Use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for the form to to call a function which generates a new booking code when a form is submitted and then sends an e-mail with the form/payment information.

Comment: I have tried placing the booking number in a column on the first sheet, but it gets deleted every time a new submission is created. Are you sure that I can make a column on the first sheet? Cos that's gonna solve a lot of problems.

Comment: Hi John. I use this method all the time for my forms. The only catch is your new columns have to be after the form columns so if your form data is columns A-F, you have to place your booking number at column G or after.